# How to save multiple pdf files in array in TypeScript Angular?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, pdf

This is the code in HTML, is an input file with Angular:

```
 <input type="file" class="btn btn-info" id="archivoPDF" #PDFfile value="Seleccionar PDF(s)" accept="application/pdf" multiple />
```

And this is the code in TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild("PDFfile") private archivoPDF=[];
private onAlta() {
    console.log(this.archivoPDF);
  }
```

But in console only I got one file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code.

```
@ViewChild("PDFfile") private archivoPDF=[];
private onAlta() {
  console.log(this.archivoPDF.nativeElement.files);
}
```

Hope it helps!